# Move a TFS 2012 project collection to Azure DevOps 2019

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I've found this article about moving collections between TFS and DevOps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-project-collection?view=azure-devops

TFS 2012 isn't listed beneath the article heading, so I'm assuming it's not possible to move a 2012 collection to Azure DevOps. Can anyone confirm or otherwise?

I guess I could just try it, but I would need to do so out of hours to avoid the disruption of detaching the collection from the live TFS 2012 server. *Now I can reattach it once it has been backed-up right?!*

Comment: Just for clarification: Are you trying to move your collection to Azure DevOps Service or Azure DevOps Server 2019 (OnPrem)?

Comment: @Flex both are on premise

Answer (score 3):

It isn't supported, as you can find in the [Azure DevOps Services Migration Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274) and the Migration tool, the current oldest version supported is Tfs2018 Update 3. So you will need to upgrade to that version first.

Do note that this will also mean that you need to upgrade the SQL server database your are using to MSSQL 2016.

Comment: It's all very confusing. This page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019?view=azure-devops) says DevOps 2019 can upgrade direct from TFS 2012 and newer. If that's true, what does it do with the SS 2012 database used by TFS 2012?

Comment: I’m sorry, I missed that you are trying to do so in the on-prem version! My advice was on the move to the SaaS offering.